# develop a video conversion software

Tags: video

How to develop a video conversion software? I couldn't find much info. What are the languages used to develop? Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is an incredibly vague question. There isn't any one language used to work with video. You can develop video conversion software in any language that you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as vague as that is you're really at the point of starting with a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=video+transcoding+libraries) for transcoding libraries.  Based on what you're asking, it sounds like you just want to develop an application that uses existing libraries in a custom way.  (There are *tons* of these out there already, but we don't need to go into that.  I see nothing wrong with writing something just for the sake of writing it.)

Can you perhaps be more specific?  What platform/language/environment/etc. are you planning to use?  What functionality are you planning to have?

Comment: actually iam using a tool called 'ffmpeg' in my console application(C#) to convert videos. just wanted to know how to develop a conversion tool like ffmpeg?

Comment: @Bala: Ah, so you want to write your own video library?  I'll be honest with you, if you're new to video processing then get ready for a steep learning curve.  Even ffmpeg uses other libraries for its purposes, etc.  You can start with the ffmpeg source code and see what you can learn from there: http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html